# Jeet: Fixed width sidebar with fluid content area

Tags: css, jeet-grid

I'm trying to figure out how to create a fluid layout with a fixed width sidebar and fluid content area using Jeet.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
.sidebar {
    width: 240px;
}
```

Looks like it is not possible with Jeet to set the content css to take rest of the layout, is it so?

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Comment: I rephrased the question, I just followed another question using different framework @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21967723/susy-2-fixed-width-sidebar-with-fluid-main-content-area

Answer (score 0):

You have to use define content width

HTML CODE

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="content-box">
        Content Here !!!! 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    <div class="content-box">
        Content Here !!!! 
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS CODE

```
.wrapper {
  color: #fff;
}
.sidebar {
  width:30%;
  display:inline-block;
  float: right;
  background: #333;
}
.content {
  width: 70%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #666;
}
.content-box {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Please check Demo Here https://jsfiddle.net/568447zu/

Comment: Thanks @Shahzeib Ali for the answer. However i'm looking for a sidebar with fixed width. Jeet does provides % width columns.

Comment: hi @tamilsweet if you need fixed width side bar so you have to use div table style. Please check this link https://jsfiddle.net/568447zu/2/

Comment: Thanks again, neat implementation.